# cannot reference "this" before supertype constructor has been called

Tags: java, constructor, supertype

I've been having trouble with some code lately:

```
public class SightsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sights> {

    static int mColorResourceId;

    public SightsAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> sights, int colorResourceId) {
        super(this, 0, sights);
        mColorResourceId=colorResourceId;
    }
}
```

I already tried using the static method in the `Sights` java class, but I still get the `this` underlined and an error message saying

> cannot reference "this" before supertype constructor has been called

PS I already reviewed the other questions of this type and they didn't really help me . I'm a complete newbie here so if someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to pass `this` to the super class constructor? The super class constructor already has access to `this`.

Comment: Try to explain **why** (= what for) you want to pass `this` to the `super` constructor. What goal do you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: And why do you want to assign a value to the static field `mColorResourceId` in the constructor? I doubt that this is what you really wanted... There *are* use cases where you might want to assign a static variable in a non-static method but you should know what you are doing when you are doing that :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confused as what to pass to the `super` constructor (belonging to [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)) as the first parameter `Context`.

For example [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) you have an example, the main part is that:

```
public class SightsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sights> {

    public SightsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> sights, int colorResourceId) {
        super(context, 0, sights);
        ...
    }
}
```

`Context` is something which must come from outside, your `SightsAdapter` must receive it as a parameter. That's the concept of *context* in applications: it is something which is injected from the environment in which the application/objects is running at the moment.

Comment: I already did that before, but I again received an error message saying "Cannot resolve method 'super(android.app.Activity, int, java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Strings>)'

Comment: "method"? Show us that code, because `super(...)` isn't a method. If you fooled the compiler into thinking it was a method call, then you must have done something weird that you aren't showing us. Show us your code.